# How do I wait for the callback to finish before I return the value?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, amazon-s3

```
public List<S3Object> ListObjects(string bucketname, string identityId)
{
    List<S3Object> objectList = new List<S3Object>();

    var request = new ListObjectsV2Request()
    {
        BucketName = bucket_name,
        Prefix = identityId
    };

    Client.ListObjectsV2Async(request, (responseObject) =>
    {
        if (responseObject.Exception == null)
        {
            List<S3Object> list = new List<S3Object>();
            responseObject.Response.S3Objects.ForEach((o) =>
            {
                objectList.Add(o);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(responseObject.Exception);
        }
    });
    //return objectList;         

    // return the object after the callback is finished, e.g. added all the objects into objectList;
    // ListObjectsV2Async method returns void, so it is not possible to use async and await. i guess?
}
```

I want to return the objectList field after the callback has finished in ListObjectsV2Async method. However, this method runs asynchronously so if I just returns the list, it will return an empty list. So how do I wait until the callback added all the object into the list before i returns?

Comment: [ListObjectsV2Async doesn't return void though?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3ListObjectsV2AsyncListObjectsV2RequestCancellationToken.html)

Comment: replace `});` with `}).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Comment: For Unity the operation does not take CancellationToken as a parameter, and instead takes AmazonServiceCallback<ListObjectsV2Request, ListObjectsV2Response> and AsyncOptions as additional parameters. And it returns void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TaskCompletionSource` can be used to capture the result of the callback, allowing for the method to be awaitable.

For example

```
public Task<List<S3Object>> ListObjectsAsync(string bucket_name, string identityId) {
    TaskCompletionSource<List<S3Object>> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<List<S3Object>>();

    var request = new ListObjectsV2Request() {
        BucketName = bucket_name,
        Prefix = identityId
    };

    Client.ListObjectsV2Async(request, (responseObject) => {
        if (responseObject.Exception == null) {
            tcs.TrySetResult(responseObject.Response.S3Objects.ToList());
        } else {
            Debug.Log(responseObject.Exception);
            tcs.TrySetException(responseObject.Exception);
        }
    });

    // return the object after the callback is finished
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Which now allows the

```
List<S3Object> objectList = await myClient.ListObjectsAsync("bucket_name_here", "identityId_here");
```

Comment: Nice! I had no idea `TaskCompletionSource` existed. Looks like C#'s take on promises. What would you recommend doing in the calling method to check for the exception/error?

Comment: @Ruzihm The awaited call can be wrapped in a try-catch like normal. Notice how the exception is given to the completion source in the call back if one exists

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure you don't want to do the operation asynchronously, then why call the asynchronous version? Use [`ListObjectsV2`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=S3/MS3ListObjectsV2ListObjectsV2Request.html&tocid=Amazon_S3_AmazonS3Client) instead:

```
public List<S3Object> ListObjects(string bucketname, string identityId)
{
    List<S3Object> objectList = new List<S3Object>();

    var request = new ListObjectsV2Request()
    {
        BucketName = bucket_name,
        Prefix = identityId
    };
    
    ListObjectsV2Response responseObject = Client.ListObjectsV2(request);
    
    if (responseObject.Exception == null)
    {
        List<S3Object> list = new List<S3Object>();
        responseObject.Response.S3Objects.ForEach((o) =>
        {
            objectList.Add(o);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(responseObject.Exception);
    }
    
    return objectList; 
}
```

---

#### [**Nkosi**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59503627/1092820) has a more elegant solution than this section. Please see their answer if you want to get the objects list asynchronously.

However, I would recommend re-engineering so that `ListObjects` returns void, takes one or more `Action<List<S3Object>>` arguments, and you invoke the appropriate action in the callback:

```
public void ListObjects(string bucketname, string identityId,
        Action<List<S3Object>> callbackSuccess, Action callbackFailure)
{
    List<S3Object> objectList = new List<S3Object>();

    var request = new ListObjectsV2Request()
    {
        BucketName = bucket_name,
        Prefix = identityId
    };
    
    Client.ListObjectsV2Async(request, (responseObject) =>
    {
        if (responseObject.Exception == null)
        {
            List<S3Object> list = new List<S3Object>();
            responseObject.Response.S3Objects.ForEach((o) =>
            {
                objectList.Add(o);
            });
            callbackSuccess.Invoke(objectList);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(responseObject.Exception);
            callbackFailure.Invoke();
        }
    });
}
```

Then, where `ListObjects` is called, you can enclose any local variables you need in the handlers. Something like:

```
int localVar1 = 123;
float localVar2 = 4.56f;

Action<List<S3Object>> handleSuccess = (resultList) => 
{
    DoStuffWithList(resultList, localVar1, localVar2);
};
Action handleFailure = () =>
{
    DoStuffWhenFail(localVar1);
};

s3Client.ListObjects("foo", "bar", handleSuccess, handleFailure);
```